# What is a good way to embed an mp3 file to a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, mp3

I use Acrobat https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/rich-media.html But I have a problem with

- Once one plays mp3, the object became black and cannot replay
- Tools > Rich Media > Select Object but cannot select the object

What will be a better way?

Comment: What is a workflow?